# Deploy to meteor.com fails with error "Cannot find module 'websocket-driver'"

Tags: deployment, meteor

When I deploy a Meteor app to meteor.com, it succeeds, but then the site displays the following error message: ***This site is down. Try again later.***

- See this very simple case: http://leaderboard666.meteor.com
- My apps work locally, both in default and `--production` mode
- The issue occurs both with default and `--debug` deployment
- Nothing is displayed in the browser console
- I work under Windows

Below is the complete log file:

```
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 10767
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS null -> starting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:216
}).run();
   ^
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: Cannot find module 'websocket-driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/npm/livedata/main/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> starting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 10767
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING }).run();
   ^
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:216
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: Cannot find module 'websocket-driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/npm/livedata/main/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 10767
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> starting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:216
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING }).run();
   ^
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: Cannot find module 'websocket-driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/npm/livedata/main/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:48 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 10767
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:48 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:48 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:49 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:216
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:49 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING }).run();
   ^
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:49 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: Cannot find module 'websocket-driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/npm/livedata/main/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:49 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:49 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:52 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 82.245.42.131
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:31:52 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 82.245.42.131
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 10767
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING }).run();
   ^
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:216
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: Cannot find module 'websocket-driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/npm/livedata/main/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:36 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /_GALAXY_ 82.245.42.131
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:32:40 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /_GALAXY_ 82.245.42.131
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS waiting -> starting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port 10767
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> running
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING /meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:216
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING }).run();
   ^
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING Error: Cannot find module 'websocket-driver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/83e8fbbc-3894-a4c1-2aae-42a599e5a110/bundle/programs/server/npm/livedata/main/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS running -> waiting
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Application crashed with code: 8
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:32 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /_GALAXY_ 82.245.42.131
[Fri Jun 13 2014 15:33:36 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /_GALAXY_ 82.245.42.131
```

Comment: What changes did you make to the leaderboard example before you deployed? Does the unmodified leaderboard example work?Which version of meteor was this with?

Comment: The unmodified leaderboard does not work either. See http://leaderboard777.meteor.com/. Meteor version is 0.8.1.3.

Comment: Some more info: 1- Uploading time is very long, almost 2 minutes for the unmodified leaderboard. 2- I said earlier that nothing is displayed in the browser console, but that is not true: there is a very brief error message when hitting refresh, which disappears immediately: `GET http://leaderboard777.meteor.com/ 503 (Service Unavailable)`

Comment: I use Stephen Darnell unofficial port for Windows (https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor). I posted an issue to ask him if my problem rings any bell. His doc says that _For some people, fibers asserts. We don't have a solid explanation for this yet, but a work-around that seems to work is to enable a compatibility layer: set __COMPAT_LAYER=WIN7RTM or set __COMPAT_LAYER=Win2000_ I don't understand what this means. Could this be related to my problem?

Comment: Yup, that's my port. The fibers issue is unrelated. When I create a leaderboard example and publish to meteor.com it works fine. Maybe best to continue debugging the issue at https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/issues/42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following investigation with @user3567351 it looks like the problem is due to long paths.
By inspecting the differences in the deployed bundle it looks like some files are silently ignored.

So for now (until the issue is fixed), please try deploying from a shorter path.